# Slow MySQL Query, Group By Order By Limit

Tags: mysql

I currently join 5 tables to select 20 objects to show the user, unfortunately if I use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` it gets really slow.

An example query looks Like this:

```
SELECT r.name, l.name, o.typ, o.id, persons, children, description, rating, totalratings, minprice, picture FROM angebote as a 
JOIN objekte as o ON a.fid_objekt = o.id 
JOIN regionen as r ON a.fid_region = r.id 
JOIN laender as l ON a.fid_land = l.id 
WHERE l.slug="aegypten" AND a.letztes_angebot >= 1 
GROUP BY a.fid_objekt ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

The EXPLAIN of the Query shows this:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys              | key        | key_len | ref                                   | rows   | Extra                                                  |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | l     | ref    | PRIMARY,slug               | slug       | 767     | const                                 |      1 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ALL    | PRIMARY                    | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                                  | 186779 | Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref    | unique_key,letztes_angebot | unique_key | 8       | ferienhaeuser.o.id,ferienhaeuser.l.id |      1 | Using where                                            |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | r     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY    | 4       | ferienhaeuser.a.fid_region            |      1 |                                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

So it looks like it doesn't use a key for the table `objekte`, the Profiling says it uses 2.7s for Copying to tmp table.

Instead of `FROM angebote` or `JOIN objekte` I tried it with `(SELECT * GROUP BY id)` but unfortunately this doesn't improve.

The fields used for `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` are also indexed.

I think I missed some basic concept here and any help will be appreciated.

Since it's most probable I made a mistake with the Tables, here the description of them:

Objekte

```
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| objekte | CREATE TABLE `objekte` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `typ` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `persons` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `children` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `rating` float NOT NULL,
  `totalratings` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `minprice` float NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_offer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `minprice` (`minprice`),
  KEY `rating` (`rating`),
  KEY `last_offer` (`last_offer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Angebote

```
    +-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| angebote | CREATE TABLE `angebote` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fid_objekt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fid_land` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fid_region` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fid_subregion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `letztes_angebot` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_key` (`fid_objekt`,`fid_land`,`fid_region`,`fid_subregion`),
  KEY `letztes_angebot` (`letztes_angebot`),
  KEY `fid_objekt` (`fid_objekt`),
  KEY `fid_land` (`fid_land`),
  KEY `fid_region` (`fid_region`),
  KEY `fid_subregion` (`fid_subregion`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2433073 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

laender, regionen, subregionen (same structure)

```
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| laender | CREATE TABLE `laender` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `iso` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `letztes_angebot` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `iso` (`iso`),
  KEY `slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `letztes_angebot` (`letztes_angebot`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=107 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you have indices for all the joins, and this would mean that grouping would still be slow even if you had indices for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this is a non standard group by. As such it will stop working when you upgrade to mysql 5.7.

The biggest problem comes from the fact that no index is used on the `objekte` table. To make matters worse you are ordering on the ratings field on that table but the index is still not being used. A possible solution is to create a composite index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX objekte_idx ON objekte(id,rating);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was it, since i also order by other columns i once tried to index them all together (id, rating, minprice) but i guess i should make 2 seperate ones. I also should be able to do the group by on another way.

Comment: well actually, mysql can only use one index per table. So making any different indexes will not lead to any further improvements. With mysql, multi column index is the way to go, but you have to get the column order right. id, rating happens to be used here but rating, id may not!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use GROUP BY here. You have not use aggregrate functions. So remove GROUP BY from query. Remove the Group By will increase query performance. Also no need to define 0 for limit.

```
SELECT r.name, l.name, o.typ, o.id, persons, children, description, rating, totalratings, minprice, picture FROM angebote as a 
JOIN objekte as o ON a.fid_objekt = o.id 
JOIN regionen as r ON a.fid_region = r.id 
JOIN laender as l ON a.fid_land = l.id 
WHERE l.slug="aegypten" AND a.letztes_angebot >= 1 
ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: I do use GROUP BY so i dont get the same object multiple times, an object can be in different subregions of a region (or regions in a country).
Or do i miss why i dont need an GROUP BY then?
The 0 is also a placeholder for bigger values.

Comment: use distinct for that

Comment: Unfortunatelly there have to be another mistake made from me, because only removing the GROUP BY doesnt help.

Comment: Can we see some evidence that removing GROUP BY will improve performance, or perhaps an explanation as to why that would be so? Incidentally, although I agree that DISTINCT is the more correct approach in the absence of any aggregating functions, GROUP BY typically performs faster!